# Выпадающее меню на PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox, menubar

Как делается выпадающее меню в *PyQt5* или в *Qt Designere*?

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, появились **`4`** кнопки, а если нажать опять эту же кнопку и все **`4`** появившиеся пропали.

Answer (score 1):

У меня установлен PyQt5. Установит его просто:

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

и вот вам ТРИ варианта выпадающего меню:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
# 1
        bar    = self.menuBar()
        self.file   = bar.addMenu("File")
        self.file.addAction("New")

        save = QAction("Save", self)
        save.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        self.file.addAction(save)

        edit = self.file.addMenu("Edit")
        edit.addAction("copy")
        edit.addAction("paste")

        quit = QAction(QIcon("D:/_Qt/__Qt/img/exit.png"), "Quit",self)
        quit.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        quit.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
        self.file.addAction(quit)

        self.file.triggered[QAction].connect(self.processtrigger)     

# 2
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItems(["option1", "option2", "option3", "option4"])
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)

    # 1 +   
    def processtrigger(self, q):
        print( q.text()+" is triggered" )

# 3
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        result = self.file.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.setWindowTitle("Qmenu")
    ex.resize(350,300)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]