# Как называется виджет прозрачной кнопки в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qmenubar

Как называется виджет в *PyQt5*, который позволяет сделать прозрачную кнопку (то есть без черных границ) и затем после нажатия вылетает список еще кнопок, которые открывают уже другие окна?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]\

**P.S.** навел курсором на прозрачную кнопку "управление пользователями", но пока не кликнул.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]\

После нажатия на кнопку "управление пользователями" вылетело еще **`3`** кнопки, которые открывают окна:

- "добавить пользователя",
- "удалить пользователя",
- "редактировать права пользователя"**

Comment: Дмитрий отвечает ли на ваш вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/988179/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pyqt/988197#988197 ?

Comment: @S. Nick нет, это выпадающий список (виджет combo box)

Comment: Дмитрий там ТРИ варианта. Один combo box, а другие смотрели ?

Comment: мне кажется, или вы пытаетесь словом "кнопка" назвать обычное главное меню?

Comment: @S. Nick да, там первый вариант то, что нужно, спасибо. Сделайте это решение как ответ, чтобы я мог его отметить

Comment: @S. Nick у меня только есть значок флажка рядом с Вашим комментарием, не могу его отметить как полезный почему-то

Comment: Дмитрий у вас было недостаточно репутации, проверьте сейчас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `QMenuBar` предоставляет горизонтальную строку меню. 
Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html

Пример использования можно посмотреть [Выпадающее меню на PyQt](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/988179/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-pyqt/988197#988197)